# Selectively disabling 'filetype plugin indent' for particular filetypes in Vim 7.3

Tags: indentation, vim

I have vim 7.3, with the setup that's provided with Ubuntu 11.04 by default. My .vimrc looks like the following:

```
set nocompatible
set autoindent
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab

filetype plugin indent on
let g:omni_sql_no_default_maps = 1 " Stops Omni from grabbing left/right keys

" syntax, colorscheme and status line directives omitted.
```

How do I selectively disable this indentation for different filetypes (eg. php, phtml, rb)?

So far I've tried `autocmd FileType php filetype plugin indent off` and a few variants, but I haven't had much luck yet.

(Removing the `filetype plugin ...` line produces the desired behaviour, but obviously affects all filetypes instead of just a few.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Prince's suggestion with autocmd does not work for me. This does:

```
filetype plugin on
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * filetype indent off
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.py filetype indent on
```

Enables `filetype indent on` selectively for python files. It's pretty cool to have also `set ai` because it works for files with indent off as a fallback.

Answer (score 6):

Note that disabling `filetype indent` is likely not what you want:

> ```
>     :filetype indent off
> ```
>
> [...] This actually loads the file
>   "indoff.vim" in 'runtimepath'. This disables auto-indenting for files
>   you *will* open.  It will keep working in already opened files.  Reset
>   'autoindent', 'cindent', 'smartindent' and/or 'indentexpr' to disable
>   indenting in an opened file.

If you want, just like suggested by this online help, to disable indenting options for some filetypes, you could put this in your `.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
au filetype php,phtml,rb call DisableIndent()

function! DisableIndent()
        set autoindent&
        set cindent&
        set smartindent&
        set indentexpr&
endfunction
```

Also, make sure to understand what these options you are turning off are by consulting the online help (e.g. `:help autoindent`).

Comment: I like the function. Then you can also call it from any file spontaneously `:call DisableIndent()`.

Answer (score 4):

All the `filetype indent on` command does is to source `$VIMRUNTIME/indent.vim`, which itself switches on filetype and calls the individual `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/[type].vim`. So you could modify the default indent.vim to ignore certain filetypes (or save a modified version of this file locally at .vim/indent.vim).

If you are unhappy with that you could try setting the plugin/indent behaviour in your vimrc separately:

```
filetype plugin on
au FileType c,vim,lisp filetype indent on
```

(and of course add the relevant filetypes). This works for me.